# load .npy file in python3.4 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I recently test the code of [Tensorflow VGG16](https://github.com/machrisaa/tensorflow-vgg/blob/master/vgg16.py). When I load vgg16.npy in python3.4. it comes out the error.
The code is like this:

```
self.data_dict = np.load(vgg16_npy_path, encoding='latin1').item()
```

The error:

```
TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

But I delete `encoding='latin1'`, just

```
self.data_dict = np.load(vgg16_npy_path).item()
```

There also comes out an error:

```
  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/tensorflow-vgg/vgg16.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.data_dict = np.load(vgg16_npy_path).item()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 394, in load
    return format.read_array(fid)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 446, in read_array
    array = pickle.load(fp)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So how to use np.load to load .npy file in python3.4?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have an old version of NumPy installed for Python 3.4. From what I can tell, the `encoding` argument was added to `np.load()` between [version 1.9.0](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) and [version 1.9.1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/generated/numpy.load.html). Try upgrading to a newer version of NumPy:

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade numpy
# ...or, if the above doesn't work on your platform:
$ sudo pip install --upgrade numpy
```